# Regular expression for specific word with space/spaces

Tags: regex, space, cpu-word

Could anyone help me with a regular expression which could work for a specific word, say "potatoes", but also for "p otatoes" or "potat oes"?

Comment: `/p\s*o\s*t\s*a\s*t\s*o\s*e\s*s/`

Comment: I will expand on @PranavCBalan answer by adding a `\<` or a `\b` at the beginning and end (since the OP said "*specific* **word**").

Comment: Important to understand and have in mind that @PranavCBalan answer will match what you've asked for ("p otatoes" or "potat oes"), and will also match spaces between more than one part of the string: "p o tatoes" or "pot at oes".

Comment: if single space is needed then use `?` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what you want:

1. Write a function to remove white spaces from your strings.
2. Once the white spaces are removed, apply the regular expression.

Comment: You don't need a regex in step 2. A string match is fine then and is faster.

Comment: OP is asking for a regular expression though.

Comment: @BramVanroy - a regex is not required if mating with a fixed string is required. For matching with a generic string regex may be required.

Comment: @blackpen - as the white space can be anywhere in the string, a cleaner approach to to trim them.